# How to ingest whole XML database to Elastic Search?

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I have 20 XML files which is the whole database. Is it possible to ingest all these 20 XML files to Elastic Search? If yes, what is the option available?

Comment: The answer is "Yes, it's possible but...". So you'll have to explain your use case in a bit more details. Maybe show how your XML is laid out and what you want to do exactly and how you would like to load that data into ES.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Python3, I propose to use [xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict)

Run `pip install xmltodict elasticsearch`

I suppose xml files have records :

```xml
<records>
    <record>...</record>
    ...
    <record>...</record>
</records>
```

So they have to be splited into record.

Edit a script called "load.py" with the following content:

```py
import sys
import xmltodict
import json
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

INDEX="xmlfiles"
TYPE= "record"

def xml_to_actions(xmlcontent):
    for record in xmlcontent["records"]:
        yield ('{ "index" : { "_index" : "%s", "_type" : "%s" }}'% (INDEX, TYPE))
        yield (json.dumps(record, default=int))

e = Elasticsearch()  # no args, connect to localhost:9200
if not e.indices.exists(INDEX):
    raise RuntimeError('index does not exists, use `curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/%s"` and try again'%INDEX)

for f in sys.argv:
    with open(f, "rt") as fin:
        r = e.bulk(xml_to_actions(xmldict.parse(fin)))  # return a dict
        print(f, not r["errors"])
```

use it with: `python load.py xml1.xml xml2.xml ... xml20.xml`